# MVC return json info when file not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have application where user can download excel report using this button:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetYearlyReport", new {@ViewBag.plantId})"  class="excelIcon" title="Get Yearly Report"></a>
```

my method looks following:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetYearlyReport(int plantId)
        {

            string fileName = Reports.GenerateYearlyReport();

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            {
                byte[] fileBytes = GetFile(fileName);

                return File(fileBytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);

            }
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = "Missing some parameters." });


        }
```

Now , wheren filename isn't empty then i got the file, but when it is then i am redirected to non existed page GetYearlyReport, while I would like to just say message from json, is that possbile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add another `if()` statement to handle the scenarios where file names are empty, and return an error and handle it client side?

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'xxx/GetYearlyReport',
            data: { plantId: plantId},
            type: 'POST',
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, exceptionThrown) {
                if (xhr.status == xxx) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            },
            success: function (data) {
                   if(data.Result = 'ERROR'){
                   //do something
                   alert(data.Message);
                   }                    
            }
        });
```

Or better define a common error handler for your ajax calls?

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, settings) {
            if (xhr.status == 401)
            {
                alert("unauthorized");
            }
            else if (xhr.status == 0) {
                alert(' Check Your Network.');
            } else if (xhr.status == 404) {
                alert('The resource you are looking for can not be found.');
            } else if (xhr.status == 500) {
                alert('Internel Server Error.');
            } else {
                alert('Unknow Error.\n' + x.responseText);
            }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine, I believe redirection is occurred in the `Reports.GenerateYearlyReport` method, there must be a way to check the result of the method before invoke it.